# Stalemate detection failure?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg, battle.net

Take a look at this case: Both Protoss and Zerg don't have the ability to gather resources anymore, Nexus and Hatchery are destroyed. Protoss still have a few base up. What's left of Zerg's base will eventually die because there's no more creep. The game detected stalemate even though the Protoss is set to win? Is this is a bug?

Here's a link to the replay: http://depositfiles.com/files/kzonxjxh4

Fast forward to the end and you'll see the Zerg's base is dying on it's own and Protoss should've won.

Comment: I'd recommend re-wording your question so that it's not specifically referencing a replay.  Perhaps something like, "How is a stalemate detected?" would be better.

Comment: @fbueckert Well, I generally know how stalemate is detected but this isn't suppose to stale so it's a stalemate failure.

Comment: @IMB It isn't a stalemate failure. The answer below is correct.

Comment: The Zerg buildings are living, and slowly dying from lack of nourishment, whereas the Protoss are already dead, but their buildings remain. Sure, in the short term the zerg buildings will die off, but did the Protoss *really* win? Who's left to celebrate?

Comment: @Robotnik Protoss should win because the basic winning rule is whoever has the last building standing wins. If you have no base you lose.

Comment: @IMB - My point was more generally about war and how there are no 'real' winners in these situations - and how there shouldn't be. :P. The Stalemate detection was apt, in my opinion.

Comment: So basically at the end of every match, both players should lose because they resorted to violent means.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A stalemate is detected when no one does the following for 6 minutes (3 mins for a warning, then 3 mins for the stalemate).

- Generate income
- Produce a unit
- Construct a building
- Research an upgrade
- Destroy an enemy building

([Source](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Stalemate_Detection))

It sounds like all of these condition were met above, so I would say it is not a "bug."

As for the Zerg buildings dying, I believe buildings off creep lose health at 2 hp/second, and that some Zerg buildings have 1000 health, which means they can survive 8.3 minutes off creep. So it is possible that the remaining Zerg buildings are dying (but not yet dead) when the stalemate is declared.

Based on the above, I would say this is not a bug in the game, but an unforeseen possibility, that is not handled by the stalemate detection logic. Given how rare this situation is, I can see that.

You could post this on Blizzard's forums, or email them about it, and maybe people would be interested in changing the system to detect this.

Comment: Not a development bug, but a design bug. I do think it should be fixed; kudos to the OP for finding this "loophole".